# How to create a JWT Token without authentication

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

- "laravel/framework": "5.7.*"
- "tymon/jwt-auth": "dev-develop"

I am trying to create a JWT token with added custom claims, **without** auth (which means that I am not looking to create a token from credentials.) This is for the purpose of creating tokens that do not require logins, such as forgot/reset-password, etc.

- using Tymon/JWTAuth (https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth)
  Since there was an issue with Latest Laravel, it was recommended to load the latest dev ( 1.0.x-dev ).
  I have tried the following code without avail:
- `class OTL extends Model implements JWTSubject`
- `use JWTAuth;`
- `use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;`
- `use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory;`

`public static function getJwtToken($customerId, $action, $token){
        $customClaims = ['action' => $action, 'customer-id' => $customerId, 'token' => $token];
        $factory = JWTFactory::customClaims($customClaims);
        $payload = $factory->make();
        $token = JWTAuth::encode($payload);
        return $token;`

I am receiving an error: `JWT payload does not contain the required claims`.

I am expecting to receive the token that holds the payload above.

Comment: Hello, maybe it's the jwt-auth package that does not allow you to use the jwt token without the claims for authentication ? Maybe you should try to use native jwt library here https://jwt.io/#libraries-io ? 
You can also try to override the method that generate you the token

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by commenting out `'exp'` in `required_claims` in the `config/jwt.php`:

```php
.....
'required_claims' => [
   'iss',
   'iat',
   //'exp',
.....
],
```

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same error and was able to solve it by updating the list of required claims in the generated configuration file `config/jwt.php`.

```
...
'required_claims' => [
    'exp',
    'sub',
    ...
],
...
```

Also make sure you have run `php artisan jwt:secret` or otherwise provided a secret key for signing.